# How to create an exe file & connect this with oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, connection, exe

I need to create an .exe file & it should be connected with an Oracle 11g DB.

scenario:
suppose I have employee table in my Oracle DB.

I want to create an exe file, which will take as user input "employee_id" and show all the employee information based on my select query in GUI mode.
The logic for select query will be on back end side code.

I just want to know, how to proceed to create this type of exe file.

Any suggestion please..

Comment: What do you mean by exe file? what tool you will used to build exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Embedded SQL".  This is how a program (an "exe" in your parlance) uses Oracle.

Basically, the idea is you include SQL "stuff" in your program, like:

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE emp_cursor SCROLL CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ename FROM emp;
```

and run it through the Oracle pre-processor, then compile and link it with Oracle's libraries.

Here is Oracle's docs on this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/pc_06sql.htm